# How does this JavaScript syntax work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am working with a jQuery plugin that has the following snippet in it:

```
$(el).siblings( panelSelector )[(effect || activationEffect)](((effect == "show")?activationEffectSpeed:false),function(){ .. some stuff .. });
```

My concern isn't really what it does in the context of the plugin, but more as to how it works.

I understand that we are first selecting the siblings of the element clicked, then I believe that we are checking which of the two, `effect` or `activationEffect` has a value, I start to get lost there. It looks like the function is a callback, but if it is I don't understand what contains the callback.

Comment: Start by formatting the code so that it's actually readable.

Comment: This is not a real question, and SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: @Matt That is exactly how the code is formatted in the plugin. If I knew what it was supposed to look like I would, and probably not need to ask this question.

Comment: @lanzz Really? answering a "how to" or "how does" question is not within the realm of SO?

Comment: @elementvine No, "explain to me how this working code works, because I am unable to read it" is not within the realm of SO. You are basically asking for a crash course in Javascript.

Comment: I call BS on that. I could read it, for the most part, I tried to show that in my question by attempting to explain what I was reading. I was under the impression that SO was built EXACTLY for people like me. who are learning, who need guidance. Apparently, it has gotten away from that, and the arrogance of reputation ahs kicked in and brought the asshole factor into those with the knowledge. Whereas they are now to smart to help the less knowledgeable to succeed.

Comment: @elementvine: I think one big issue with your question is the rather vague title which makes it look bad from a quick look. Voted to reopen (yes, even though I was one of the users who voted to close).

Comment: No worries, thank you fro answering it. I haven't been on SO in quite a bit. I guess it's changed a bit. It used to be that you could ask a question and not have everyone jumping on you about it being an invalid question. It makes complete sense to allow an explanation of logic behind a function.

Comment: I voted to re-open. @Ianzz: this is "a specific programming problem" (which is what the FAQ says to ask about) - the `object["functionName"]()` syntax does seem strange to newer JS coders, and it is kind of hard to Google an explanation for it even without the extra complications in the code shown so why not ask here? elementvine - I think people can be a bit too quick to close questions here sometimes, but I'm not sure that name-calling helps. I'm happy to share the knowledge I have, but then sometimes I vote to close things...

Comment: I don't believe I called anyone a name. I stated a point that SO has become just like every other forum out there, where users who are very knowledgeable & spend a lot of time on the forum, and are quick to hammer on someone who does not spend as much time or is new to the forum. I'm sure we all have commented on some forum back in the 2000' and were made to feel a dunce by some arrogant, highly regarded, individual who spends a a lot of time on the forum. There was no name calling though, I made a reference to the type of attitude I was under the impression SO was cerated to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing you need to know to understand the code is that `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equal.

Let's split it to make it even clearer:

```
var sibs = $(el).siblings(panelSelector);
sibs[(effect || activationEffect)](...);
```

The second line calls whatever method name is stored in `effect` or `activationEffect` (the first true-ish value wins) on `sibs`.

`((effect == "show")?activationEffectSpeed:false)` is the first argument of that call and `function(){ ... }` the second one.

Comment: +1. I was just writing almost the same thing, but you beat me to it. (Wait - you answered the question _and_ voted to close it?)

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice the close votes and comments earlier - and IMO there is no need in deleting a correct answer just because you are voting to close it. But I see your point, it indeed looks kind of odd to close a question you answered... Besides that, instead of closing it most likely would have been better to improve the title.